# python: mock a module

Tags: python, mocking

Is it possible to mock a module in python using `unittest.mock`? I have a module named `config`, while running tests I want to mock it by another module `test_config`. how can I do that ? Thanks.

config.py:

```
CONF_VAR1 = "VAR1"
CONF_VAR2 = "VAR2"
```

test_config.py:

```
CONF_VAR1 = "test_VAR1"
CONF_VAR2 = "test_VAR2"
```

All other modules read config variables from the `config` module. While running tests I want them to read config variables from `test_config` module instead.

Answer (score 15):

If you're always accessing the variables in config.py like this:

```
import config
...
config.VAR1
```

You can replace the `config` module imported by whatever module you're actually trying to test. So, if you're testing a module called `foo`, and it imports and uses `config`, you can say:

```
from mock import patch
import foo
import config_test
....
with patch('foo.config', new=config_test):
   foo.whatever()
```

But this isn't actually replacing the module globally, it's only replacing it within the `foo` module's namespace. So you would need to patch it everywhere it's imported. It also wouldn't work if `foo` does this instead of `import config`:

```
from config import VAR1
```

You can also mess with `sys.modules` to do this:

```
import config_test
import sys
sys.modules["config"] = config_test
# import modules that uses "import config" here, and they'll actually get config_test
```

But generally it's not a good idea to mess with `sys.modules`, and I don't think this case is any different. I would favor all of the other suggestions made over it.

Comment: Very nice, although when I test this I can't get it to mock `foo.config` before actually importing foo (as I can with `config.var1` say). This means that any code executed when foo is imported will use the original config module. Any suggestions?

Comment: @PeterGibson Right, that's another limitation of this approach.  I'm not aware of any way around it.

Comment: @PeterGibson I don't think there is a way to patch code executed when foo is imported without messing with `sys.modules`. I've described it in my answer. But unless this import patching is necessary, I would stick to dano's approach.

Answer (score 11):

**foo.py:**

```
import config

VAR1 = config.CONF_VAR1

def bar():
    return VAR1
```

**test.py:**

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock

import test_config


class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_one(self):
        with mock.patch.dict('sys.modules', config=test_config):
            import foo
            self.assertEqual(foo.bar(), 'test_VAR1')
```

As you can see, the patch works even for code executed during `import foo`.

Comment: what if your module is not called `config` but `config.foo`? Wrinting  `mock.patch.dict('sys.modules', config.foo=test_config)` would not do...

Comment: @naxa, you can pass a dictionary to this function `patch.dict('sys.modules', {'config.foo': test_config})` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.dict))

Comment: How would you patch a module for **all** tests?

Comment: @kev, if you mean all tests in a TestCase, you should create a patcher with `patch.dict()` and `start()` it in `setUp()`, then `stop()` it in `tearDown()`. If you mean all tests in a project, this sounds like a good Question on it own. I suppose you could have a custom test runner with separate config (django seems to do something like this). But first of all I would consider changing design to avoid patching altogether.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the module is already imported in the test module itself. For example, in my unit tests, I'm importing `pyspark` (a third-party library) to create objects for some unit tests. But then in another module, I'm optionally importing pyspark. I'd like to mock the pyspark import from the other module to raise ImportError, but can't because it's already imported at the top of my unit tests. Ideas?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to mock an entire module just mock the import where the module is used.

`myfile.py`

```
import urllib
```

`test_myfile.py`

```
import mock
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

  @mock.patch('myfile.urllib')
  def test_thing(self, urllib):
    urllib.whatever.return_value = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this following setup

configuration.py:

```
import os

class Config(object):
    CONF_VAR1 = "VAR1"
    CONF_VAR2 = "VAR2"

class TestConfig(object):
    CONF_VAR1 = "test_VAR1"
    CONF_VAR2 = "test_VAR2"


if os.getenv("TEST"):
    config = TestConfig
else:
    config = Config
```

now everywhere else in your code you can use:

```
from configuration import config
print config.CONF_VAR1, config.CONF_VAR2
```

And when you want to mock your coniguration file just set the environment variable "TEST".

Extra credit:
If you have lots of configuration variables that are shared between your testing and non-testing code, then you can derive TestConfig from Config and simply overwrite the variables that need changing:

```
class Config(object):
    CONF_VAR1 = "VAR1"
    CONF_VAR2 = "VAR2"
    CONF_VAR3 = "VAR3"

class TestConfig(Config):
    CONF_VAR2 = "test_VAR2"
    # CONF_VAR1, CONF_VAR3 remain unchanged
```

Answer (score 1):

If your application ("app.py" say) looks like

```
import config
print config.var1, config.var2
```

And gives the output:

```
$ python app.py
VAR1 VAR2
```

You can use `mock.patch` to patch the individual config variables:

```
from mock import patch

with patch('config.var1', 'test_VAR1'):
    import app
```

This results in:

```
$ python mockimport.py
test_VAR1 VAR2
```

Though I'm not sure if this is possible at the module level.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this same problem too. I need to test some magic code that modifies a modules `__dir__` and `__getattr__` function, so mocking using a class is not an option for me.

I then realized Django uses modules to configure settings, so in their tests, they must be "mocking" modules too.
Here's how they did it:

```py
from types import ModuleType

m = ModuleType("mymodule")
print(m)  # <module 'mymodule'>
m.CONF_VAR1 = "conf1"
m.CONF_VAR2 = "conf2"
```

Django source code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2.4/tests/settings_tests/tests.py#L366