# How can I mock a module that is imported from a function and not present in sys.path?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I am `unittest`ing code which contains a method that does a local import.

```
def function_under_test():
    import unknown.dependency
```

(I'm not using an import at the top of the `.py` file because it may or may not be present when the function is called.)

Mocking `unknown.dependency` in the usual way only works if it can be found somewhere in `sys.path`.  Otherwise, the call to `patch` fails (it refuses to mock something it cannot look at):

```
with mock.patch('unknown.dependency'):
    function_under_test()
>>> ImportError: No module named 'unknown'
```

The docs suggest that I should patch to the namespace where the module is used -- in this case, `function_under_test`.  However, when that namespace is a function, this doesn't cut it.  The call to `patch` succeeds, but the actual import statement is still referencing the original, non-existing `unknown` module, which cannot be found.

```
with mock.patch('method_under_test.unknown'):
    print("fails")
>>> ImportError: No module named 'unknown'
```

So, how do I replace the dependency module with a mock, if the module itself does not exist *and* it is imported from a function?

Comment: What is the goal here? To skip the test when the dependency is missing, or to simulate that *if* the dependency is missing, the code-under-test handles this in a specific way?

Comment: And for import statements, the accepted method is to patch `sys.modules`. There is *no object* in a `import` statement, only names, so there is no object *to* patch.

Comment: The goal is to test the code-under-test, acting like the dependency is there, without it actually being present.

Comment: So you want to mock the *entire module*? Then this is a dupe of the post you linked; you'd mock `sys.modules` to insert a mock object to replace the dependency.

Comment: I see why it's a dupe now.  It's irrelevant if the import statement is at the top of the file or in a function -- the issues is that the module is not present and I still want to mock it.

Answer (score 17):

### Mock the import only

The easy way out is to move the import statement into a separate function.

```
def get_dependency():
    import unknown.dependency
    return unknown.dependency

def function_under_test():
    module = get_dependency()
    # use module
```

That makes it easy to mock out only that 'helper' function.  This has the disadvantage that it requires a change to the code under test.  It does work though:

```
with mock.patch('get_dependency'):
    function_under_test()
```

### Mock the module

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900878/python-mock-a-module/23992082#23992082), you can add the mocked module straight to `sys.modules` so that Python can find it regardless of whether it's present in `sys.path` or not.

```
with mock.patch.dict('sys.modules', unknown=mock.MagicMock()):
    function_under_test()
```

Comment: What is `unknown`? What does it stand for, is it mandatory? What's the meaning behind?

Comment: @kev It's a Python module that may not be present at test time.

Comment: find it very useful for mocking `plpy` which is only available inside postgres with plpythonu extension.