# Python patch module for all test cases after it has been imported

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I am still struggling with [mock and patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock).

I have a couple of test cases where some of them have imports (at the top) which then import [pika](https://github.com/pika/pika).

It would be nice to mock `pika` without having to change my code at all.

What I have been doing usually so far:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.patch_pika = patch('<package>.rabbitmq.pika')
    self.mock_pika = self.patch_pika.start()
```

That fails if another package imports *.rabbitmq* before *setUp* runs (which happens apparently when the test runner imports the test cases). I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23992082/1252307), suggesting to use [patch.dict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.dict). Using it the same way as above:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.patch_pika = patch.dict('sys.modules', pika=Mock())
    self.mock_pika = self.patch_pika.start()
```

results in `self.mock_pika` being `None`.
As `Mock()` is called and passed as parameter, I thought this might be the right approach:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.mock_pika = Mock()
    self.patch_pika = patch.dict('sys.modules', pika=self.mock_pika)
```

Unfortunately that fails with *AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'modules'*

I am pretty clueless how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated. I would like to avoid having wrapped all my test cases with `with patch.dict()`.

Comment: Could you explain what mean `<package>.rabbitmq.pika`?

Comment: I’ve just obfuscated the python package the file lives in.

Comment: Is it part of your project?

Comment: Yes. The file rabbitmq.py lives in my package and it imports pika. It handles connecting, reconnecting and some custom functions like returning the size of a queue.

Comment: could you add some test case and `rabbitmq.py` to the question?

Comment: Will do when back at computer.

Comment: I think I was wrong in my 1st example. I had to execute the code after patching. It is ok to do the import first. Unfortunately I can't recall the changes I made. Hence posting the file would be useless as it is working now. Either way thanks for looking into this!