# Pytest mock: how to patch an import statement inside a function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have a function which imports a module inside a function. Something like following snippet

```
def parse_file(self, filename):
    if(filename.endswith("json"):
         import custom_json_parser   # <--- How to patch this.? 
         return custom_json_parser.extract_file(filename)
```

For following reasons I have to patch it,

- I don't have `custom_json_parser` in my environment
- Or I don't want to unit test it again while I am unit testing `parse_file` function

How can we patch such dynamically imported modules.?

I am looking for something like the following snippet. (the following snippet is just pseudocode & not correct syntax wise & would give exception)

```
@patch("file_name.parse_file.custom_json_parser", autospec=True)
def test_parse_file(self, patch_custom_json_parser)
    . . .
```

**Edit**:

The import statement in a module can be easily patched. But what I am struggling though is the import statement inside a function. When a function imports a module, it will not be imported as a global module and will only reside in the local memory of the function.

Comment: @StephenRauch, Can we please reopen the question.? As I have mentioned in the Edit section, the question completely different from the one tagged. I am really stuck on this and can not get any possible way to patch the module which is imported inside a function. I hope you consider the request. Thanks,

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23992082/7311767) does exactly what you are after, I just tested it.  `mock.patch.dict('sys.modules', custom_json_parser=mock.Mock())`

Comment: Oh, it does work. I am sorry I didn't realize that it would also solve this problem. Thanks for making me realize.!